# C++ ostream : no operator match << & expected initializer before '&' token

Tags: c++, ostream

Thanks in advance for any help! This program is a student registration program.

Input is via file and the results are out to file. Then general idea is to learn c++, method overloading -including operators and `fstream`'s. I'll post the code the compiler points to but please let me know if you want to see other code.

When I go to build the compiler error points to my header file method, outside of my class but inside the `#endif`. See below.

```
    std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & os, const Registration & R);
```

The implementation of this file is as such:

```
std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream & os, const Registration & R  )
{ os  << "Student ID: "   << R.GetStudentId() << "\n"
      << "Semester:   "   << R.GetSemester()  << "\n \n";

for(unsigned i = 0; i < R.GetCount(); i++)
{
    os  << "\tUnit Name : " << R.GetName(i) << "\n"
        << "\tUnit Id : " << R.GetId(i) << "\n"
        << "\tCredit Points : " << R.GetCredits(i) << "\n"
        << "\tStudent Mark : " << R.GetResult(i) << "\n"
        << "\tDate : " << R.GetDay(i) << " " << R.GetMonth(i) << " " << R.GetYear(i) << "\n\n";
}

os  << "Total Credits :" << R.GetCredits() << "\n"
    << "Number of Units : " << R.GetCount() << "\n"
    << "Average Mark : " << R.GetAverage();

return os;
}
```

And main()

```
 int main()
{
ifstream infile( "rinput.txt" );
if( !infile ) return -1;

Registration R;
infile >> R;

ofstream ofile( "routput.txt" );

ofile << R; // Error Here RE- no match for 'operator<<'

cout << "\nComputation completed. Check output file. \n";

return 0;
}
```

Thanks again for any and all help, hope this isn't a rookie error... it's late where I am.

Edit: I have "using namespace std" & #include in all header files.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @Kerrek - Have that in all my header files :)

Comment: @MasterSketchiggle Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that enables everyone to reproduce your errors.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would find that extremely hard to do. As the program was working previously prior to implementing a new class date. The program structure is Registration with a array of object results, which entails it a float "result" and two objects date & unit.
My point being that it seems that something in the implementation of adding date seems to have messed it all up. And not sure if posting the whole program is.... what is expected on the site. It would be hard to recreate, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

This code is valid, except:

- Need to `#include <iostream>`
- Need to either add `using namespace std;` or add `std::` before `ifstream`, `ofstream`, and `cout`.
- Need to overload `istream` for your `Registration` class.

Edit: Please add `std::` rather than `using namespace std;`. I only mentioned it for completeness. :)

Comment: _"Need to either add `using namespace std;`"_ That causes me physical pain.

Comment: At uni atm. And at this stage we taught to use "using namespace std" 
May I ask why it seems that you suggest I always put in std:: when coding?
Additionally, I have iostream in all headers and have "using namespace std" in all headers. 
I have overloaded the istream for Registration class but haven't included the code as errors don't seem to relate to that. Shall I update question with this included?

Comment: Sure. The reason is that you should always avoid `using namespace` because it hacks around C++ namespaces, which are there for reasons that will become increasingly apparent as you work on larger codebases and find conflicting names (including ones that conflict with names in the std namespace). `using namespace` was only made part of the standard so that legacy code (written prior to namespace support) would compile with minimal modification.

Comment: "using namespace std" is OK for class projects, but for real work you need to be explicit. Sooner or later, "using namespace _whatever_" will pull in something you really don't want.

Comment: Feel free to add additional code, and especially to include the exact error message your compiler is giving you.

Comment: @AdamLeggett thanks for the heads up I shall start doing that now. Better to get used to industry std's...pun intended =P. 

I'm going to try rebuild from last version prior to date class implementation and take a much better testing approach them coding everything and than testing.... it was late... i know this is dumb :( but most of the things I've been doing aren't overly comprehensive... again it just about making good habits.

Should I get the same errors .... I'll be back. :)